# Python PRAW - can't login, RedirectException

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to log into a Reddit account through python using praw.

```
import time
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0')
r.login('user', 'pass')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/Reddit/logintest.py", line 5, in <module>
    r.login('user', 'pass')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/__init__.py", line 1334, in login
    self.user = self.get_redditor(user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/__init__.py", line 949, in get_redditor
    return objects.Redditor(self, user_name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/objects.py", line 746, in __init__
    fetch, info_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/objects.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.has_fetched = self._populate(json_dict, fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/objects.py", line 133, in _populate
    json_dict = self._get_json_dict() if fetch else {}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/objects.py", line 126, in _get_json_dict
    as_objects=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/decorators.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/__init__.py", line 561, in request_json
    retry_on_error=retry_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/__init__.py", line 402, in _request
    response = handle_redirect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/__init__.py", line 376, in handle_redirect
    url = _raise_redirect_exceptions(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw-2.1.21-py2.7.egg/praw/internal.py", line 164, in _raise_redirect_exceptions
    raise RedirectException(response.url, new_url)
praw.errors.RedirectException: Unexpected redirect from http://www.reddit.com/user/user/about/.json to https://www.reddit.com/user/user/about/.json
```

I've googled this and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my version of PRAW was outdated and I needed to update. `pip install praw --update` because `pip install praw` won't actually update your version.